# Explanation of Classic Probability Question

Tags: probability

After some reading on the internet I've found two different answers to ***part b) Sampling With Replacement*** of the same question: "An urn contains 5 red, 6 blue, and 8 green balls. If a set of 3 balls is randomly selected, what is the probability that each of the balls will be (a) of the same color; (b) of different colors? Repeat under the assumption that whenever a ball is selected, its color is noted and it is then replaced in the urn before the next selection"

One of the answers being: (5/19)(6/19)(8/19)

and the other being: 3! x ((5/19)(6/19)(8/19))

I think the one that multiplies the probabilities by 3! to account for the different ways you can arrange the choices makes sense, but I'm not entirely sure which one is right

Comment: $\frac{5}{19}\cdot\frac{6}{19}\cdot\frac{8}{19}$ is for *very specifically* drawing a red ball *and then* drawing a blue ball *and then* drawing a green ball.  There are many other ways to draw balls and them all be different colors other than just that.

Comment: If you want to formalize everything to see what is going on, let $R_1$ be the event that the first ball drawn is red.  Similarly define $R_2, R_3, B_1,\dots, G_3$.  Now, notice that the event "All balls are different colors" corresponds to the event $(R_1\cap B_2\cap G_3)\cup (R_1\cap G_2\cap B_3)\cap (B_1\cap R_2\cap G_3)\cap\dots$.  When calculating the probability of this you may expand this using rule of sum and rule of product, turning unions inside of the parentheses into addition outside of parentheses (since mutually exclusive) and intersections into multiplication (since independent)

Comment: @JMoravitz yeah that also makes the most sense to me too, being able to draw them in different orders of course. Thanks!

Comment: I had a typo if you would notice, all $\cap$'s outside of parentheses should have in fact been $\cup$'s.  Outside of window of opportunity to edit, but not truly worth deleting and rewriting former comment.